# Cypher Query - return nodes of a tier 2 relationship that are related to 2 or more indirect nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Unsure of how best to word this - in the below diagram

[image: neo]

I am trying to return all nodes where the 2nd tier node is related to 2 or more of the 1st tier nodes, but only where the first tier nodes are different. So in the example picture I want to return grey node 660082, green node 110258, and all the pink nodes & relationships that are related to it. I do not want to see, for example, green nodes where pink nodes have 2 relationships to the same green node. so far my cypher looks like this

```
MATCH (i:IFB_Flagged)-[r]->(m:Matters)<-[r2]-(ie:Indirect_Entity)
WITH i, ie,r, collect(m) AS overlap 
WHERE size(overlap) > 1 and i.id = '660082'
RETURN i, ie, overlap
```

This does appear to work as it filters out pink nodes that have only one link to a green node, however I can't figure out how to only return pink nodes where the related green nodes are not the same node

UPDATE

When adding a distinct to the collect & removing the where clause entirely I get a completely different graph, however it is actually closer to what I want to show [image: neo2]

I still want to see all pink nodes that relate to more than one green node - however I do not want to see the pink nodes that only relate to one green node (the 6 pink nodes at the bottom left of the screen)

Here is my Cypher - I am not sure why collect(distinct m) doesn't work in this case?

```
MATCH (i:IFB_Flagged)-[r]->(m:Matters)<-[r2]-(ie:Indirect_Entity) 
WITH i, ie,r, collect(distinct m) AS overlap 
WHERE i.id = '385886' 
RETURN i, ie, overlap limit 20
```

Comment: But in your example the green node is the same for all red nodes and the same for both relations of each red node... Anyway, try putting a distinct clause in your collect, this way: `collect(distinct m)`

Comment: The question's wording does not match what you actually seem to want.

Comment: Red nodes in the question are actually more like pink. Let's wait for the OP to get this straight.

Comment: edited my original question for clarity

Comment: "I am not sure why collect(distinct m) doesn't work in this case?" it doesn't work because you left variable `r` in the `WITH` clause, so it will aggregate on each `r` separately.

Comment: Ah yes I can see that now. Thanks for your help, question answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword for `collect` ([docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating)):

> The `DISTINCT` operator works in conjunction with aggregation. It is used to make all values unique before running them through an aggregate function.

Also, you can move the check for `id` inside the `MATCH` clause for conciseness.

**Update.** Try this.

```
MATCH (i:IFB_Flagged)-[r]->(m:Matters)<-[r2]-(ie:Indirect_Entity) 
WHERE i.id = '385886'
WITH i, ie, collect(distinct m) AS overlap 
WHERE size(overlap) > 1
RETURN i, ie, overlap
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I believe your solution is the right answer. However, seems to me that the problem description provided in the question does not match with the described output. You agree?

Comment: I agree the colors in the question are off.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks so much